# OS Edit/Paste menu for Qt Quick.2 TextField

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquickcontrols2

How do I get the OS specific paste menu for a QtQuick.Controls 2* TextField on a right click on selected text.

That works:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

TextField
{
    placeholderText: qsTr("Filter")
    selectByMouse: true
}
```

and gives me the menu, while

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

TextField
{
    placeholderText: qsTr("Filter")
    selectByMouse: true
}
```

this does nothing on right-click.

I'm using version 5.9 LTS and I'm stuck with it for a while.

It works neither on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 with 5.9 manually installed nor on Windows 10, mingw{32,64} on msys2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I can see in the Qt bug tracker, it is a missing feature ([QTBUG-35598](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35598)), even in Qt 5.10.

I think the reason for that IMHO, is to ensure the application has a consistent look and feel irregardless from the platform.

So I'm afraid you have to implement your own context menu. Here is a snippet I came up with:

```
property int selectStart
property int selectEnd
property int curPos

TextField
{
    id: textInput
    placeholderText: qsTr("Filter")
    selectByMouse: true

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
        hoverEnabled: true
        onClicked: {
            selectStart = textInput.selectionStart;
            selectEnd = textInput.selectionEnd;
            curPos = textInput.cursorPosition;
            contextMenu.x = mouse.x;
            contextMenu.y = mouse.y;
            contextMenu.open();
            textInput.cursorPosition = curPos;
            textInput.select(selectStart,selectEnd);
        }
        onPressAndHold: {
            if (mouse.source === Qt.MouseEventNotSynthesized) {
                selectStart = textInput.selectionStart;
                selectEnd = textInput.selectionEnd;
                curPos = textInput.cursorPosition;
                contextMenu.x = mouse.x;
                contextMenu.y = mouse.y;
                contextMenu.open();
                textInput.cursorPosition = curPos;
                textInput.select(selectStart,selectEnd);
            }
        }

        Menu {
            id: contextMenu
            MenuItem {
                text: "Cut"
                onTriggered: {
                    textInput.cut()
                }
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: "Copy"
                onTriggered: {
                    textInput.copy()
                }
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: "Paste"
                onTriggered: {
                    textInput.paste()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code to save and restore the selection comes from KDE plasma (have look [here](https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/114437/diff/3/#)) because by default TextField will reset the selection after right click.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend using **MouseArea** to open the menu, it causes the TextArea's hover effect unavailable. I've looked into this problem and if you use **TapHandler** instead, this will involve a qt bug: [TapHandler on TextField (for showing right click context menu) stops working in Qt6](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-99887) which will prevent you from using TapHandler unless you are on version 6.4.2 or above.

The most appropriate method to use is to use **onPressed** or **onReleased** in the TextArea, it works fine.

```
onPressed: function(mouse) {
    if (mouse.button != Qt.RightButton) return
    var point = mapToGlobal(mouse.x, mouse.y)
    textArea.showMenu(point.x, point.y) //custom method to show Menu
}
```

I hope this will be of help to those who come after me

Comment: Note that the new syntax IIRC is `function onPressed(mouse)`

Comment: @ניר No, this is a TextArea slot (handler), not a custom function